# angular.js:13550 Error: [ngModel: nonassign]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my JavaScript file:

```
var app=angular.module("isolateScope",[]);
app.controller("attrScope",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.gem="ruby";    
}]);
app.directive("diffScope",function(){
   return{
       scope:{
           gemType:'@',
           twoWay:'=',
       },
       //template:'@scope:<input type="text" ng-model="gemType"/><br/><label>=Scope</label><input type="text" ng-model="twoWay"/>'
   } 
});
```

In my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="attrScope">
        <input type="text" ng-model="gem" />
        <div class="panel-group">
            <diff-scope gem-type="{{gem}}" two-way="gem">
                @scope:<input type="text" ng-model="gem-type"/><br/><label>=Scope</label><input type="text" ng-model="twoWay"/>
                </diff-scope>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I got an error:

> angular.js:13550 Error: [ngModel: nonassign] Expression 'gem-type' is non-assignable. Element: `<input type="text" ng-model="gem-type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">`

Comment: You can't use `gemType` with `ng-model`, since `gemType` is oneway binding attribute

Comment: @SatejS gem type is just  attribute isolate scope to access gem

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ng-model='gemType'` ?

Comment: @Greg gemType doesn't work to access "gem" in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From error page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign?p0=gem-type&p1=%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20ng-model%3D%22gem-type%22%20class%3D%22ng-pristine%20ng-untouched%20ng-valid%22%3E)

> This error occurs when expression the ngModel directive is bound to is
>   a non-assignable expression. Examples of non-assignable expressions
>   include:
>
> ```
> <input ng-model="foo + bar">
> <input ng-model="42">
> <input ng-model="'oops'">
> <input ng-model="myFunc()">
> ```

In your code, you have used `ng-model="gem-type"` which is not valid syntax for `ng-model`. Use something like `ng-model="gType"` or any valid `ng-model`.

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ebLQXh4quPZmblHYfOTq?p=preview)

Comment: That's right but  text boxes are not updating . do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @PradhabanNandhakumar that's a different question. I have posted the solution for the problem you have mentioned. Anyway, do you want `gemType:'@'` to be populated in text box?